# Persistent Victory Charts VictoryVoronoiContainer tooltips on click

Tags: javascript, victory-charts

I'm implementing a combination VictoryLine and VictoryScatter chart with Victory-Charts using *VictoryVoronoiContainer* for displaying values at the mouse hover location. I need to make these hover details persist on click at multiple locations.

Example of just hover data: https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-voronoi-container/

Specifically, if a user clicks while a given popup is active, using VoronoiDimension='x' in this case, the hover popup details remain visible at their X coordinate. In a perfect world, any number of these would be visible.

Using events (https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/events/). I can sort of fake it on a scatter point click (https://jsfiddle.net/kn6v9357/3/) but with the voronoidimension hover it's difficult to see the points and you have to be awfully precise with the click. Plus, when there's overlap you only trigger a click on the top layer, so overlapping data isn't shown on what persists.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Code for VictoryScatter events in from the jsFiddle (note this doesn't do what I want) with just a scatter component to keep it simple:

```
<VictoryChart
    containerComponent = { <VictoryVoronoiContainer 
      voronoiDimension="x" 
      //voronoiBlacklist={['Scatter0','Scatter1','Scatter2',]}
      labels={
        (d) => {
          return (
            `${d.market}: ${d.metric1}`
          )
        }
      }
    /> } 
  >
  <VictoryAxis 
    style = {{tickLabels: {fontSize: 8,angle: -15}}}
    label = 'Date'
  />
  <VictoryAxis dependentAxis 
    label = {this.state.metric === 'metric1' ? 'Metric 1' : 'Metric 2'}
    style = {{tickLabels: {fontSize: 8}, axisLabel: {padding: 40}}}
    axisLabelComponent = { <VictoryLabel style = {{fontSize: 12}} dx = {20} /> } 
  /> 
  { this.viewablePlaces.map((place, i) =>
      <VictoryGroup 
        animate = {{easing: "cubic",duration: 500,onLoad: {duration: 0}}}
        key = {place + String(i) + 'Group'}
        data = {this.get_data(place)}
        x = {(d) => moment(d.date).format('MMM YY')}
        y = {this.state.metric === 'metric1' ? 'metric1' : 'metric2'} 
      >
      <VictoryScatter
        key = {place + String(i) + 'Scatter'}
        name = {"Scatter"+i}
        style = {{  
          data: {fill: "#455A64",cursor: "pointer"},
          labels: {fontSize: 12,padding: 2}
        }}
        size = {2.5}
        labels={(d) => d.market + ': ' + String(d.metric2)}
        labelComponent = { 
          <VictoryTooltip
            orientation = {"top"}
            pointerLength = {5}
            pointerWidth = {3}
            cornerRadius = {3}
          />
        }
        events={[
          {
            target: "data",
            eventHandlers: {
              onMouseOver: (props) => {
                return [
                  {
                    target: "labels",
                    mutation: {active: true}
                  }
                ];
              },
              onMouseOut: (props) => {
                return [
                  {
                    target: "labels",
                    mutation: (props) => props.name === 'clicked' ? {name: 'clicked', active: true} : null
                  }
                ];
              },
              onClick: (props) => {
                return [
                  {
                    target: "data",
                    mutation: (props) => props.style.fill === 'orange' ?
                      null : {style: Object.assign({}, props.style, {fill: 'orange'}), size: 3.5}
                  },
                  {
                    target: "labels",
                    mutation: (props) => props.name === 'clicked' ?
                      null : {name: 'clicked', active: true}
                  }
                ];
              }
            }
          }
        ]}
      /> 
    </VictoryGroup>
  )}
  </VictoryChart>
```

Edit: 
Here's another example with persistent points, but I need to find a way to also make the labels persist.
https://codesandbox.io/s/oq1w9xj8q6